# Unmasking and handling satellite data in python

Tags: python, spyder, mask

I was working with satellite data and by reading the variable it created a masked array by masking the fill values. But now I can't extract any values from that masked array.
How can I unmask the array
The code is mentioned below

```
import glob

import os

import netCDF4 as nc

import numpy as np

#listing all nc files in this folder


os.chdir(r'I:\Data\AOD\MODIS_AQUA_AOD\2004')

myfiles = glob.glob('*.nc')


ds=nc.Dataset(myfiles[0])

#now myfiles has every nc file name saved as an array

#reading lat and lon one time because same band in every file


lats=ds.variables['lat'][:]

lons=ds.variables['lon'][:]

aods=[]     #will save the AOD data in this array

# Creating Loop and reading AOD  Data

for i in range(len(myfiles)):
    dt=nc.Dataset(myfiles[0],'r')
    
    aod=dt.variables['MYD08_D3_6_1_AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined_Mean'][:]
    aods.append(aod)
```

now I want to extract values of specific latitude and Longitude from the list of masked array list (aods) but I am unable to do so
any solutions?

Comment: Please include your code and you may want to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @ViktoriyaMalyasova I included the code any solution is appreciated